# Why is upgrading App Engine SDK so painful in IntelliJ?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gcloud

How do I get IntelliJ to upgrade my Google App Engine SDK and the global libraries which depend on it?

Or at minimum, how do I get IntelliJ to update the global libraries entry for my App Engine SDK libraries without having to go through and manually select numerous different directories?

Right now, every time I update App Engine, I need to go and manually reconfigure the entire global library. It won't let me just change it from say 1.9.1 to 1.9.2. It forces me to redefine every single one of the paths completely.

These include the following directories in the SDK:

```
/lib
/lib/agent
/opt/user/appengine-endpoints-v1
/opt/user/datanucleus/v2
/shared
/user
/user/orm
```

In addition to this, I need to change my Application Servers settings for GAE to use the new SDK path and update its path to the new location of the /lib/shared dir in the SDK. There are some unresolved bugs (since IDEA 12) related to this where the dialog will break if the old SDK is no longer found.

Why can't I just tell it to change from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2? It is a major pain and nightmare that I keep having to go through every 2 weeks on both my laptop and desktop. It is just a waste of time! There has to be a better way...

I'm not using Maven or Gradle for this project atm. Is that the only solution to this? Will creating a Gradle configuration resolve all of this and allow me to update to the latest SDK libraries without all of the hassle across multiple machines? Does anyone have an example Gradle script for this?

The following issue has been opened with JetBrains: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123643
If you would like the usability of GAE with IntelliJ to improve, please star and vote for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use maven with [appengine-maven plugin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven). Then you can just change GAE version in the config file and IDEA will update libraries automatically for you.

Even if you do not use maven, you do not need to set all libraries by hand. Commercial version of IDEA has the [AppEngine plugin](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_app_engine.html): just add AppEngine Facet to the project and define local path to SDK, then all dependent libs will be updated.

Comment: I have been using and configuring the Google App Engine facet for my module. It does allow me to specify the SDK path without much trouble. But I haven't found that it allows me to compile without adding the various App Engine .jars to the artifact, which causes me all kinds of issues. I'll give it another shot with just configuring the Facet and not touching the other pieces... hope it works.

Comment: If I remove the global library and use the Facet, there are a lot of build failures due to servlet and other missing libraries. I can use the Application Server's libraries in the module instead of the Global library. That saves me one step, but I still need to add all of the above paths into that Application Server library definition (and manually change them all every upgrade). This is 'working' for my basic apps which don't use GCS or datastore, but my more robust app is giving me exceptions and failing with 503 when configured this way. Ugh.

Comment: That issue was fixed by adding the Application Server Libraries to the artifact. So I am one step better now. I no longer need to update both the Global Library and the Application Server definition. But I still need to update the Application Server definition (per machine) and the Facet with every upgrade of the GAE SDK (per project).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question! It seems that IntelliJ expects you to use Maven or so.

However, please note that I found this answer very helpful:
[How do I create a new Google App Engine project in IntelliJ 12 which works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970666/how-do-i-create-a-new-google-app-engine-project-in-intellij-12-which-works/22925719#22925719) (note that I'm using IntelliJ IDEA v. 13).

Particularly the part:

> You also need to configure your Application Server under Settings->IDE
>   Settings->Application Servers. Add a Google App Engine Dev Server and
>   specify your SDK directory.

It seems that if you do these steps first, then the configuration of AppEngine projects is smoother (i.e. does not require artifacts, or libraries).

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by installing the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) and then using [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) to install the App Engine Java SDK.

When this is done, you end up with the SDK installed here:

`/opt/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/appengine-java-sdk`

Then upgrading the SDK leaves it in the same place. So IntelliJ IDEA just keeps working without any issues!

Comment: As of July 2015, gcloud no longer distributes the appengine-java-sdk so this great fix to my workflow is now ruined.